# How to get the values individually in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, dictionary

I have this in my dictionary i need to get my values sepeartely like the date is  Mar  5 06:49:10 2021 GMT.Like how to print the values indvidually.please help me with this?

```
  dict = {'Ernst & Young Nederland LLP': ['Mar  5 06:49:10 2021 GMT', '2048']}
```

Comment: Could you include an example of your desired output?

Comment: What happens if there are multiple keys ? Do you want to list all values of all keys flat or list them separately ? If so, how ?

Comment: I need to print Date is Mar  5 06:49:10 2021 GMT

Comment: Use `print('date is :',dict['Ernst & Young Nederland LLP'][0])`

Comment: don't name your dictionaries 'dict', unless you want trouble later on...

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate your dictionary and pick only the first value:

```
d = {'Ernst & Young Nederland LLP': ['Mar  5 06:49:10 2021 GMT', '2048']}

for v in d.values(): print(v[0])
```

If you need also they keys replace `.values()` with `.items()` like so:

```
for k,v in d.items():...
```

This will give the following output:

```
Mar  5 06:49:10 2021 GMT
```

Comment: can be simplified using `dict.values()`

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the dict values and pick the first entry in the value

```
d = {'Ernst & Young Nederland LLP': ['Mar  5 06:49:10 2021 GMT', '2048']}
for v in d.values(): print(v[0])
```